# Minio. Can't create bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, docker-compose, minio

Its my docker-compose.yml file.

```
  minio:
    image: minio/minio
    command: server /data
    ports:
      - "54322:9000"
    volumes:
      - minio-data:/data
    environment:
      MINIO_ACCESS_KEY: minio
      MINIO_SECRET_KEY: minio123

  create_buckets:
    image: minio/mc
    depends_on:
      - minio
    entrypoint: >
    /bin/sh -c "
              sleep 10;
              /usr/bin/mc config host rm s3;
              /usr/bin/mc config host add --quiet --api s3v4 s3 http://minio:9000 minio minio123;
              /usr/bin/mc mb --quiet s3/vais;
              /usr/bin/mc policy set public s3/vais;
              exit 0;"
```

And when I start it I see an error

```
create_buckets_1  | Removed `s3` successfully.
create_buckets_1  | Added `s3` successfully.
create_buckets_1  | mc: <ERROR> Unable to make bucket `s3/vais`. Put "http://minio:9000/vais/": dial tcp 172.18.0.7:9000: i/o timeout
create_buckets_1  | mc: <ERROR> Unable to set policy `public` for `s3/vais`. Get "http://minio:9000/vais/?location=": dial tcp 172.18.0.7:9000: i/o timeout.
```

When i try to add bucket manually with command `docker container run minio/mc mb --quiet s3/vais`

I see error:
`` mc: <ERROR> Unable to make bucket `s3/vais`. The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records. ``

What I'm doing wrong?